# Convert XML to specific JSON structure with powershell

Tags: xml, json, powershell

Need a help on converting an xml to a specific json structure.
XML would look like this,

```
<DataGrid> 
<DataRow>
    <RowID>1</RowID>
    <Date>26/10/2014</Date>
    <Owner>ABC Company</Owner>        
    <Make>Mitsubishi</Make>
    <Model_Family>Lancer</Model_Family>
    <Submodel>Lancer 2.0 GSR Hatch CVT</Submodel>
    <Origin/>
    <CC_Rating>1997</CC_Rating>
    <Weight>2000</Weight> 
</DataRow> 
<DataRow>
    <RowID>2</RowID>
    <Date>26/10/2014</Date>
    <Owner>ABC Company</Owner>        
    <Make>Mazda</Make>
    <Model_Family>Axela</Model_Family>
    <Submodel/>
    <Origin>Japan</Origin>
    <CC_Rating>1497</CC_Rating>
    <Weight/> 
</DataRow>
 <DataRow>
    <RowID>3</RowID>
    <Date>26/10/2014</Date>
    <Owner>Test Company</Owner>        
    <Make>Kia</Make>
    <Model_Family>Sorento</Model_Family>
    <Submodel/>
    <Origin>Korea</Origin>
    <CC_Rating>2200</CC_Rating>
    <Weight>2500<Weight> 
</DataRow>
<DataRow>
    <RowID>4</RowID>
    <Date>26/10/2014</Date>
    <Owner>Test Company</Owner>        
    <Make>Nissan</Make>
    <Model_Family>Pathfinder</Model_Family>
    <Submodel>SUV<Submodel>
    <Origin>Japan</Origin>
    <CC_Rating>2000</CC_Rating>
    <Weight>2000<Weight> 
</DataRow>
```

There can be one or more files in above format, my requirement is to read all those files and group them by Owner and call a REST web service by converting those object to JSON. Required JSON format will be as follows.

```
{
"batches": [
    {
        "Owner": "ABC Company",
        "Date": "2014-10-26",
        "Vehicles": [
            {                    
                "Make": "Mitsubishi",
                "ModelFamily": "Lancer",
                "SubModel": "Lancer 2.0 GSR Hatch CVT",
                "Origin": null
                "CcRating": "1997",
                "Weight": "2000"                    
            },
            {                   
                "Make": "Mazda",
                "ModelFamily": "Axela",
                "SubModel": null,
                "Origin": "Japan",
                "CcRating": "1497",
                "Weight": null                   
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Owner": "Test Company",
        "Date": "2014-10-26",
        "Vehicles": [
            {                   
                "Make": "Kia",
                "ModelFamily": "Sorento",
                "SubModel": null,
                "Origin": "Korea",
                "CcRating": "2200",
                "Weight": "2500"                  
            },
            {                    
                "Make": "Nissan",
                "ModelFamily": "Pathfinder",
                "SubModel": "SUV",
                "Origin": "Japan",
                "CcRating": "2000",
                "Weight": "2000"                   
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

This need to be done using windows powershell, Iam a java guy and have no idea how to do it using powershell except calling remote ftp server and read all xml files.
Really appreciate, if someone could help me this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## XML Stuff

Powershell has some stuff for working with XML. First, it has a native `[XML]` datatype. You can cast strings to XML like so:

```powershell
$someXml = '...' # pretend there's XML in there!
$xmlObject = [XML]$someXml
```

The `ConvertTo-Xml` cmdlet takes a string or other object and converts it to XML, either as a Document (XML object), a string, or a stream (array of strings). You can pass to it a string, or an object:

#### Reading From a File:

```powershell
$xmlObject = [XML](Get-Content -Path C:\Path\to\my.xml)
$xmlObject = Get-Content -Path C:\Path\to\my.xml | ConvertTo-Xml
```

### Working with XML Objects

Once you've got your object, you can access nodes as properties:

```powershell
$xmlObject.SomeNode.SomeChild
```

You can also use XPATH to select a single node or multiple nodes:

```powershell
$xmlObject.SelectSingleNode("//this[1]")
$xmlObject.SelectNodes("//these")
```

Or to do it in a more powershell way you might use the `Select-Xml` cmdlet:

```powershell
$xmlObject | Select-Xml "//these"
```

I'm leaving out a lot of other stuff, especially manipulation, because it seems like you just need to find information and group it together.

## JSON Stuff

There isn't a lot to know about JSON in powershell.

Use `ConvertFrom-JSON` to convert existing JSON into an object, and use `ConvertTo-JSON` to convert an object into a JSON string.

## Hashtables

Sometimes called hashes or associate arrays, as I'm sure you're aware. In Powershell you use them like this:

```powershell
$hash = @{
    Key1 = 'Value1'
    Key2 = 'Value2'
    Key3 = 10
}

# on one line:
$hash = @{ Key1='Val1';Key2='Val2' }

# adding pairs
$hash['NewKey'] = 'NewVal'
$hash.NewKey = 'NewVal'

# retrieving
$hash['NewKey']
$hash.NewKey
```

The value can be an array, an object, another hash, etc.

```powershell
$complex = @{
    ThisThing = @{
        Key1 = 'val1'
        Key2 = 5
    } 
}
```

## REST

`Invoke-RestMethod` is the easiest way to make REST calls in Powershell (requires version 3.0+).

## How to Proceed

Once you're able to parse the information out of the XML, build a nested hash or array of hashes that contains the structure you want, and then convert it to JSON:

```powershell
$mySpecialHash | ConvertTo-JSON
```

Take special note of how arrays and hashes are represented in the resulting JSON and maybe change the way you're building them to get the output you want.

If you have specific questions about a particular method or piece of code, then post specific questions on SO about that piece of it.

## References

### XML

- [A very detailed and useful page on working with XML in Powershell](https://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/powershell/powershell-data-basics-xml/)
- [ConvertTo-Xml](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849889.aspx)
- [Select-Xml](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849968.aspx)

### JSON

- [ConvertTo-JSON](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849922.aspx)

### REST

- [Invoke-RestMethod](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849971.aspx)

Comment: This answer indeed helped me to complete my task hence accept as the answer

Comment: how is convert to xml distinct from import cli xml?

Comment: @NicholasSaunders `Import-CliXml` is the counterpart to `Export-CliXml`. CLIXML is a format specific to PowerShell for serializing and deserializing objects. The documentation page says it best: `This cmdlet is similar to Export-Clixml except that Export-Clixml stores the resulting XML in a Common Language Infrastructure(CLI) XML file that can be reimported as objects with Import-Clixml. ConvertTo-Xml returns an in-memory representation of an XML document, so you can continue to process it in PowerShell. ConvertTo-Xml does not have an option to convert objects to CLI XML.`