# How to load my custom PowerShell module?

Tags: powershell, powershell-module

I have the execution policy set Unrestricted, I've added the folder to the modules path, I have a module in the folder with the same name as the folder, yet I can only load the modules by file path.  Any idea why?  I need modules to load other modules, I'd like my own folder, and I'd like to not have to keep calling scripts in the same folder.

```
PS C:\Users\russell.GOISC> $env:PSModulePath
[...];C:\Projects\OI2\SiteMaintenanceScripts\PowerShellModules

PS C:\Users\russell.GOISC> Get-ExecutionPolicy
Unrestricted

PS C:\Users\russell.GOISC> Import-Module EZTNameExtensions -Verbose
Import-Module : The specified module 'EZTNameExtensions' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
...

PS C:\Users\russell.GOISC> Import-Module C:\Projects\OI2\SiteMaintenanceScripts\PowerShellModules\EZTNameExtensions.psm1
 -Verbose
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\Projects\OI2\SiteMaintenanceScripts\PowerShellModules\EZTNameExtensions.psm1'.
WARNING: The names of some imported commands from the module 'EZTNameExtensions' include unapproved verbs...

PS C:\Users\russell.GOISC> Import-Module PowerShellModules
Import-Module : The specified module 'PowerShellModules' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
...

PS C:\Users\russell.GOISC> Import-Module C:\Projects\OI2\SiteMaintenanceScripts\PowerShellModules\PowerShellModules.psm1
 -Verbose
VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\Projects\OI2\SiteMaintenanceScripts\PowerShellModules\PowerShellModules.psm1'.
VERBOSE: Exporting function 'Get-Function'.
VERBOSE: Importing function 'Get-Function'.
```

The suggested link [How can I re-use/import script code in PowerShell scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27138483/how-can-i-re-use-import-script-code-in-powershell-scripts) references only the built-in locations and absolute import paths, neither of which fit my needs.  I want my scripts and modules near each other but not in the same folder and want to deploy to other machines without having to duplicate folder location.

Comment: No, that basically tells me to use the default PS folders or use a complete path, neither of which meet my scenario.  But thanks.

Comment: It does not meet your scenario, but it is the way that it works! You aren't able to do what you're asking.

Comment: The MS documentation claims that I can.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878350(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: As far as I can tell, that documentation supports what I'm saying. The module must be in one of a few specific locations **or** you must update `%PSModulePath%`. Could you point out where it says otherwise; maybe I am missing it?

Comment: I did update PSModulePath.  You can see in the code sample my entry is the final value for $env:PSModulePath

Comment: Ah, I see the problem now then. Have a look at the documentation you linked to, specifically the `Use the Correct Module Directory Name` subheading. Your module needs to be in its own directory, within the directory that's listed in the path.

Comment: I elided it, here's the full output: PS C:\Users\russell.GOISC> $env:PSModulePath
C:\Users\russell.GOISC\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;C:\Progr
am Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program
 Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\ResourceManager\AzureResourceManager;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs
\Azure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement;C:\Projects\OI2\SiteMaintenanceScripts\PowerShellModules

Comment: So only one module per folder?  That's going to be worse than all scripts and modules in one folder, at least if I want to use the new Visuasl Studio Powershell project type.

Comment: Yes, so in your `PowerShellModules` folder, there should be one folder per module (named the same as the module name) and within that folder are all of your module's files and (optionally) subdirectories, like your `.psm1`, `.psd1`, `.psxml` etc.