# PowerShell returning a PSSession object

Tags: powershell

I'm new to PowerShell and trying to write some Exchange Online modular scripts for various tasks. The model I'm working on is to have a control script that calls other parameterised scripts to perform reusable functions.

I've written a connection script, but when I return the PSSession object to my command script I can't import the session, it is somehow getting cast to an object.

How should I be sharing this session around my scripts?

Control script:

```
$session = .\Connection.ps1 -user admin@mydomain.com
Import-PSSession $session
```

Connection script (summary):

```
Param (
[string]$userparam
)
$UserCredential = Get-Credential -userName $userparam
$Exch = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $UserCredential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
return $Exch
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is happening because when you run a script it runs in its own scope. You'll get the return value as an object, but it won't be "live" anymore because the scope in which it was created doesn't exist.

Second, it sounds an awful lot like [what you really want is a module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27138623/3905079). Write these pieces as functions, not scripts, and then make them into a single package by writing them as a module.

Doing so would solve your scope problem as well, but the advantages are many.

Comment: Sounds like a plan to me. I'll give this a try and mark as answer if it works out!

Comment: Thanks again for your help, @briantist.